# Different drift velocities in the same conductor

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, conductors

We know unlike charges attract and like charges repel.

The magnitude of this force of attraction or repulsion decreases as the distance between the charges increase.

As a result the force exerted due to the potential difference on the electrons decreases as it moves away from the negative terminal in any circuit. Thus the magnitude of drift velocity would also change at different points of the circuit.

As a result the current flowing in different parts of the conductor would also be different in magnitude.
But we do not find it so.

Why??

I would be highly obliged if somebody could help me clear my doubt.
Thank you

Comment: What you say would be true if the only field that a charge carrier experiences is that of due to the terminals of the voltage source.  But that is not true.  A carrier feels that force plus the force due to every other carrier.  The dynamics are complicated to present, but the conclusion of it all is that the electric field in a wire is constant across the cross section and the length.

Comment: Sir could you please explain this in a bit more detail.

Comment: It's not an easy ride.  I refer you to [this paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.5095939)  and [this related simulation](https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/matterandinteractions/folder/matterandinteractions/program/18-SurfaceCharge).  The simulation is very rich, and will take some time to digest.

Answer (score 0):

> The magnitude of this force of attraction or repulsion decreases as the distance between the charges increase.

That's true but magbitude of  force due to external field on a charge particle is given by $F=\vec Eq$ . Since  the electric field is constant magnitude of drift velocity is constant.

Comment: Sir is there in any proof or explanation to the saying, that the electric field is constant,and the force on a charged particle is constant no matter where the charged particles is, between the electric field. It would really be helpful if you could kindly explain this to me

Comment: @SagnikDhar https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306594/how-is-the-electric-field-created-by-a-battery-inside-a-conducting-wire-constant